# Are people who "think a lot about" God, Jesus, right and wrong more likely to "qualify" to go to heaven?

Tags: heaven

King David (probably) went to heaven. That was in spite of the fact the he committed a number of sins, the most egregious of which was stealing Bathesheba from Uriah.

The some is probably true of his son King Solomon.

David wrote the book of Psalms, and Solomon the books of Proverbs, Ecclesiastes, and Song of Solomon. That shows that they thought a lot about God, Jesus, and right and wrong.

Then there was the story of the prophet (I believe it was Daniel) who "mediated on the law day and night."

In John 3:16, it says "For God so loved he world that he gave his only begotten son, that whosoever believeth in him shall not perish put have eternal life."

All other things being equal, are people that "think a lot about" God more likely to have the faith they need to go to heaven than people who don't? Put another way, would another king who committed "Bathesheba" and other similar sins but don't "think a lot about God" be more likely to go to Hell than King David? And are there examples of people in the Bible who "think a lot about God"  but probably did not go to heaven?

**Note:** This is the revised version of a question that was originally closed. This version postulates "faith," as the precondition for going to heaven, and asks if "thinking" is tied to "faith."

My comment to an answerer below was, "To ask the question "your way," is someone who "thinks a lot about God and Jesus and right and wrong" more likely to "believe in God's son [and therefore meet] the condition for eternal life?" –

Comment: Actually, the most egregious was probably *murdering* (by proxy) Uriah.  He also repented, "Create in me a clean heart, oh God".  Where there is repentance, there is forgiveness.

Comment: @SoftwareMonkey: I consider those acts "two sides of the same coin." As I remember, Nathan accused David of "stealing" Bathsheba from Uriah, just as the rich man stole the lamb from the poor man.

Comment: The Pharisees, Sadducees, and Scribes thought a lot about God and it availed them nothing.  Their minds were blinded (2 Cor. 4:4) by the god of this age.  What is required is a new birth and a renewed mind.

Comment: @MikeBorden: You gave the beginnings of a good answer. Will you vote to reopen the question so that you (and others) can give a "full" answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Thinking a lot about God" does not get one into heaven.  Evidence:  John 3:16 says to believe in God's son is the condition for eternal life. Ephesians 2:8-9 says that faith, not works (which would include "thinking"), is the means through which one is saved.  Heaven: no.

Two bible passages can answer the question of whether "a lot" of devotion to the Lord earns one a special place, any merits with God. In  Matthew 20:1-16, the vineyard workers who showed up at the last hour get same wages as those who worked all day.  In Luke 15:11-32, the older son (who was a good boy all his life) is rebuked for his anger at the Father's love for the prodigal son.

Comment: Fair enough. To ask the question "your way," is someone who "thinks a lot about God and Jesus and right and wrong" more likely to "believe in God's son [and therefore meet] the condition for eternal life?"

Comment: Yes. My evidence would be "faith cometh by hearing." The more you hear these things in your head, the greater the chance of it taking root.